# Characteristic Function as projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space and denote $\chi_E$ by the characteristic function of a measurable set E. Then the operator $Q_E f=\chi_E f$ defined in $L^2 (X, \mu)$ is a projection. Under what condition on $E$,$F$ is $Q_E+Q_F$ a projection?

I don't really understand what I need to do in order to show that an operator is a projection? If someone could provide a proof I this will help out immensely.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to look up and write down the definition of projection that you're working with. A common one is $P^2 = P$.

Comment: Is this true for $\chi_E$?

Comment: Yes, any single set $E$ defines a projection: $Q_E Q_E f = \chi_E \chi_E f = \chi_E f$.

Comment: Why is $\chi_E\chi_Ef=\chi_Ef$?

Comment: Write down the definition of $\chi_E$. Write down the definition $\chi_E \chi_E$.

Comment: I know that $\chi_E$ is 1 on E and 0 off E. But what is the defn. of $\chi_E\chi_E$

Comment: $\chi_E(x) \chi_E(x) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$ if $x \in E$, and $\chi_E(x) \chi_E(x) = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$ if $x \not\in E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $P = Q_E + Q_F$ is a projection if $P^2 = P$.
- If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $Q_A Q_B = Q_B Q_A = 0$.
- You can write $P = Q_{E \backslash F} + 2Q_{F\cap E} + Q_{F \backslash E}$.

Comment: When I square $P=Q_E+Q_f$ I get $Q_E+Q_F+Q_EQ_F+Q_FQ_E$. So I need $Q_EQ_F=Q_FQ_E=0$. So is disjointness the only condition needed?

Comment: Yes; you can prove that such an operator is a projection, and you can further prove that it is **not** if $E\cap F \neq \emptyset$ (take $f$ supported in $E\cap F$, and compute $Pf$ and $P^2f$).

Comment: Is there a proof somewhere which backs your second assertion in the hints?

Comment: You should be able to prove it directly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help and patience!